# Error 1242 Mysql subconsulta

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Tengo un problema con esta subconsulta.

Tengo en una tabla dos id, `cveLider` y `cveOperador` que están relacionados con `cveEmpleado`, tengo que obtener el nombre de ambos, lo hice a través de una subconsulta pero obtengo el error

> ERROR 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

He aquí mi consulta.

```
SELECT idSolicitud
    ,(SELECT CONCAT (
                sol.cveLider
                ,'  '
                ,em.nomEmpleado
                ,em.ap1Empleado
                ,' '
                ,em.ap2Empleado
                )
        FROM empleado em
            ,solicitud sol
        WHERE sol.cveLider = em.cveEmpleado) AS l
    ,(SELECT CONCAT (
                s.cveOperador
                ,'  '
                ,emp.nomEmpleado
                ,emp.ap1Empleado
                ,' '
                ,emp.ap2Empleado
                )
        FROM empleado emp
            ,solicitud s
        WHERE s.cveOperador = emp.cveEmpleado) AS o
FROM solicitud
GROUP BY idSolicitud
```

Comment: De primera instancia te recomendaría que ejecutes los *subqueries* por separado, de esta forma te darás cuenta cuál es que te está devolviendo más de un registro, luego, ya identificado sería cuestión que realizaras un LIMIT 1 para que solo te regrese un solo registro en el *subquery*

Comment: Hi hi, gracias :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como estas usando una subconsulta para retornar una celda, debes asegurarte que solo se retorne un valor o limitarla a que solo retorne una fila con `LIMIT 1`.

Algo parecido a lo siguiente.

```
select CONCAT(sol.cveLider,'  ', em.nomEmpleado, em.ap1Empleado,' ', em.ap2Empleado)
    from empleado em, solicitud sol
    where sol.cveLider=em.cveEmpleado LIMIT 1
```

Pero te recomiendo que redefinas tu consulta, pues si se retornan muchos registros, esta sub-consulta como la estas usando puede poner lenta la ejecución del query

Comment: muchas gracias ya lo resolví y si, tenía que ver con eso n-n"

Answer (score 0):

El problema es exactamente lo que te indica: Una de las subqueries devuelve más de una fila. Habría que contar con una copia de la base de datos para verificar, pero es que

`select ... from empleado em, solicitud sol where sol.cveLider=em.cveEmpleado`

o

`select ... from empleado emp, solicitud s where s.cveOperador= emp.cveEmpleado`

coinciden con más de una fila. Probalas por separado para verificar cuál es. Solo es posible usar subqueries cuando estas devuelven una única fila.

Sin embargo, te recomendaría usar `join`, esa consulta se ve bastante mal. Por favor, publicá la estructura y datos de ambas tablas para poder ofrecerte más detalles.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya lo resolví :) era algo sencillo

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer sólo tenía que hacer algunas modificaciones a mi subconsultas

```
    select idSolicitud,
    (select distinct CONCAT(sol.cveLider,'  ', em.nomEmpleado, em.ap1Empleado,' ', em.ap2Empleado)
    from empleado em
    where sol.cveLider=em.cveEmpleado limit 1) as l,
    (select distinct CONCAT(sol.cveOperador,'  ', emp.nomEmpleado, emp.ap1Empleado,' ', emp.ap2Empleado)
    from empleado emp
    where sol.cveOperador= emp.cveEmpleado limit 1) as o
    from solicitud sol
    group by idSolicitud, cveLider, cveOperador
```