# En MySQL me sale el error 1242. Para Delete y Insert Into

Tags: mysql, insert

Tengo una tabla Ventas que se relaciona mucho a muchos con una tabla Productos
por esa razón cree la tabla *DetalleDeLosProductosEnLaVenta*

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  DetalleDeLosProductosEnLaVenta  (

   ID_Productos  INT NOT NULL,
   ID_Ventas  INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( ID_Productos ,  ID_Ventas ),
   INDEX  fk_Productos_has_Ventas_Ventas1_idx  ( ID_Ventas  ),
   INDEX  fk_Productos_has_Ventas_Productos1_idx  ( ID_Productos  ),
   CONSTRAINT  fk_Productos_has_Ventas_Productos1 
   FOREIGN KEY ( ID_Productos )
   REFERENCES  Productos  ( ID_Productos )
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT  fk_Productos_has_Ventas_Ventas1 
   FOREIGN KEY ( ID_Ventas )
   REFERENCES  Ventas ( ID_Ventas )
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
;
```

Para borrar ventas hechas en una fecha primero intento borrar la relación en la tabla *DetalleDeLosProductosEnLaVenta*

```
DELETE DetalleDeLosProductosEnLaVenta.* 
FROM DetalleDeLosProductosEnLaVenta
WHERE 
DetalleDeLosProductosEnLaVenta.ID_Ventas  = 
(select Ventas.ID_Ventas from Ventas
        where Ventas.Fecha = '2017/01/21' );
```

Sucede que para esa fecha hay más de dos ventas y me sale el error

> **ERROR 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row**

Revisé muchas páginas como: [Error 1242 Mysql subconsulta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41967/error-1242-mysql-subconsulta)

Donde me dice que use **limit** 1, es decir limite a que solo borre solo uno.

Agradezco su colaboración...

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hay un error de logica en lo que estas intentando.. porque vas a borrar todas las ventas de una fecha? si quisieras solamente borrar una, no te bastaria con el id de la venta?

Comment: He editado la pregunta con un esfuerzo suplementario debido a la cantidad de negritas que pusiste en el código. Para futuras preguntas evita esa práctica (poner negritas en el código), no tiene ninguna utilidad. De cara a analizar el código es más útil colocarlo identado, como está ahora. Además es más fácil también para ti.

Comment: Gracias Chicos por el editado. Necesito es borrar todas las ventas de esa fecha. Sigo investigando :)

Comment: Por favor, lee todos los links que te pase. :)

Comment: Puedes borrarlos también de esta forma: **`DELETE DetalleDeLosProductosEnLaVenta 
FROM DetalleDeLosProductosEnLaVenta INNER JOIN Ventas ON DetalleDeLosProductosEnLaVenta.ID_Ventas  = 
 Ventas.ID_Ventas WHERE Ventas.Fecha = '2017/01/21' ;`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo en tu `CREATE TABLE` que la tabla `detalles` se relaciona con la tabla `ventas` mediante `IdVenta`, puedes borrar usando JOIN.

Fíjate que sería casi la misma consulta que usarías para el `SELECT`:

```
DELETE dp 
FROM Detalles_Productos_20170913 dp
INNER JOIN Ventas_20170913 v
ON dp.ID_Ventas = v.ID_Ventas 
WHERE v.Fecha = '2017/01/21' ;
```

#### `Código:` <kbd>[`DEMO EN REXTESTER`](http://rextester.com/VWRQ29758)</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  Ventas_20170913  (
   ID_Ventas  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   Fecha DATETIME 
)
;

INSERT INTO Ventas_20170913 (Fecha)
    VALUES
    ('2017/01/21'),
    ('2017/01/21'),
    ('2017/01/22'),
    ('2017/01/22'),
    ('2017/01/22')
    ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  Productos_20170913  (

   ID_Productos  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   Nombre VARCHAR (70) 
)
;

INSERT INTO Productos_20170913 (Nombre)
    VALUES
    ('Producto 1'),
    ('Producto 2'),
    ('Producto 3'),
    ('Producto 4'),
    ('Producto 5')

    ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  Detalles_Productos_20170913  (
   ID_Productos  INT NOT NULL,
   ID_Ventas  INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( ID_Productos ,  ID_Ventas ),
   INDEX  fk_Productos_has_Ventas_Ventas1_idx  ( ID_Ventas  ),
   INDEX  fk_Productos_has_Ventas_Productos1_idx  ( ID_Productos  ),
   CONSTRAINT  fk_Productos_has_Ventas_Productos1 
   FOREIGN KEY ( ID_Productos )
   REFERENCES  Productos_20170913  ( ID_Productos )
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT  fk_Productos_has_Ventas_Ventas1 
   FOREIGN KEY ( ID_Ventas )
   REFERENCES  Ventas_20170913 ( ID_Ventas )
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
;

INSERT INTO Detalles_Productos_20170913 (ID_Productos,ID_Ventas)
    VALUES
    (1,1),
    (1,2),
    (3,3),
    (2,4),
    (4,5)
;

-- Antes de borrar 

SELECT * FROM Detalles_Productos_20170913 dp
INNER JOIN Ventas_20170913 v
ON dp.ID_Ventas = v.ID_Ventas ;

-- Borrar

DELETE dp 
FROM Detalles_Productos_20170913 dp
INNER JOIN Ventas_20170913 v
ON dp.ID_Ventas = v.ID_Ventas 
WHERE v.Fecha = '2017/01/21' ; 

-- Después de borrar

SELECT * FROM Detalles_Productos_20170913 dp
INNER JOIN Ventas_20170913 v
ON dp.ID_Ventas = v.ID_Ventas ;
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
-- Antes de borrar

ID_Productos    ID_Ventas   ID_Ventas   Fecha
1               1           1           21.01.2017 00:00:00
1               2           2           21.01.2017 00:00:00
3               3           3           22.01.2017 00:00:00
2               4           4           22.01.2017 00:00:00
4               5           5           22.01.2017 00:00:00


--Después de borrar

ID_Productos    ID_Ventas   ID_Ventas   Fecha
3               3           3           22.01.2017 00:00:00
2               4           4           22.01.2017 00:00:00
4               5           5           22.01.2017 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Si quisieras borrar todas las ventas de una fecha en particular, bastaria con que cambiaras el where de tu query a esto:

```
DetalleDeLosProductosEnLaVenta.ID_Ventas  in
(select Ventas.ID_Ventas from Ventas
    where Ventas.Fecha = '2017/01/21' );
```

Porque? por que la clausula in se usa para igualar una columna a una lista de datos, que es lo que quieres en este caso.

Answer (score 0):

Chicos gracias por sus respuestas todas son válidas. Mi problema era que el WorkBench me daba errores y usando consola veo que todas las soluciones son acertadas. Debo actualizar mi WorkBench. Gracias